# Trying to create a 3D model of Kelvin’s Tetradecahedron / Tetrakaidecahedron polyhedra

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polyhedra, octave

How can I go about creating a 3D model / 3D image of a **Kelvin’s Tetrakaidecahedron Cell / Tetrakaidecahedron**.  I planned on using Octave to 3D model an image it mathematically then convert that into a Blender 3D file for animation.  But how does one begin to model it?

Some background on it:

https://ardentmetallurgist.wordpress.com/2020/07/26/tetradecahedron/

"Lord Kelvin is one of them and his proposed structure referred to as ‘Kelvin Cell’. Kelvin cell possesses alternative quadrilateral and hexagonal faces, i.e., there are six planar quadrilateral faces and eight equiangular non-planar hexagonal faces. OK, I know it’s crucial to imagine such structure. Let us start with an Octahedral structure. If we cut regular octahedron from all meeting points by using quadrilateral face, this will automatically create alternative hexagonal and quadrilateral structure. This structure holds 36 edges and 24 corners."

http://soft-matter.seas.harvard.edu/index.php/Tetrakaidecahedron_(Kelvin_Cell)

[image]

Comment: A key question here is: *which* tetradecahedron are you after? As the Wikipedia entry notes (**emphasis** mine), "There are **1,496,225,352** topologically distinct convex tetradecahedra". The ArdentMetallurgist describes a truncated octahedron, which should be straightforward to model, but the image you provide (again from Wikipedia) is quite different. (Please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4176439/edit) to make clarifications. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: What does it even _mean_ to model a body? In a way, the picture in your question ***is*** a model, though apparently not of the kind that you want. What is it that you want, then?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm trying to create the Kelvin’s Tetrakaidecahedron Cell

Comment: @Blue I was looking for Kelvin’s Tetrakaidecahedron Cell.  I'll update the question.

Comment: The Kelvin's cell is a truncated octahedron. That's **not** what you have on the picture, so I'd rather update that as well. Now to the point. "Create" is awfully ambiguous too. Your third link shows a net; print it on paper, cut it out, glue where it says to glue, and then you'll have a 3D model. But you don't seem to want that either. What do you want, then? The 3D coordinates? They are quite trivial to find. $(\pm1,\pm2,0)$ plus all permutations will do.

Comment: @RickT: You should show a picture of the Kelvin Cell, rather than the irrelevant Wikipedia image. Also, you should include relevant descriptive passages from the ArdentMetallurgist to make you question self-contained, instead of requiring readers to visit multiple external sites and try to figure out what matters to you.

Comment: @Blue ok  I made some more changes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the polyhedron you are talking about is the one with the $24$ vertices at $(0, \pm 1, \pm 2)$, $(0, \pm 2, \pm 1)$, $(\pm 1, 0, \pm 2)$, $(\pm 2, 0, \pm 1)$, $(\pm 1, \pm 2, 0)$, and $(\pm 2, \pm 1, 0)$, then, if we use notation $(n_x, n_y, n_z; d)$ for an outwards facing halfspace, so that point $(x, y, z)$ is in the halfspace if and only if $x n_x + y n_y + z n_z \le d$, the $14$ halfspaces defining this convex polyhedron are $(0, 0, \pm 1; 2)$, $(0, \pm 1, 0; 2)$, $(\pm 1, 0, 0; 2)$, and $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1; 3)$.

The six square faces are at distance $1$ from origin with unit normals along the coordinate axes ($(\pm 1, 0, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1, 0)$, or $(0, 0, \pm 1)$).

The eight hexagonal faces are at distance $\sqrt{3}$ from origin with diagonal unit normals ($(\pm\sqrt{1/3}, \pm\sqrt{1/3}, \pm\sqrt{1/3})$).

There are multiple ways in which these can be used in Blender to construct a solid primitive; I recommend you ask [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) about the details.